# How can I get a list with m tails? Python

Tags: python, list, random, coin-flipping

So I need to create a list with m tails. The elements of the list will be a random choice between tail and head.
I did like :

```
Def S(m):
    list=[]
    counter=0
    signs=["head","tail"]
    while counter<(m):
        list.append(random.choice(signs))
        for k in list:
            if k=="tail":
               counter+=1
    print(list)
```

So this one gives me a list but not with m tails. I think the while is wrong here but I  am not sure how to write the code.  Can you help me to change it?

Comment: it's not clear to me what you want, the list printed has to include just tail?

Comment: can you show your expected output with this code?

Comment: maybe you just want this?  `return ['tail'] * m`

Comment: No, I want a list with elements head and tail. But in the list all together I want m tails. Maybe if m=100 I want to add elements(head or tail) until I get 100 tails in the list.

Comment: Lets say m=3. Then maybe ["head", "tail","head","tail","tail"]

Comment: Calling a list `list` is an awful choice since it is the name of a built-in function. Also, just test if the newest flip is a tail. Don't retest all of the old flips as well. There is no reason to have that inner for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will work:

```
from random import choice

def S(m):
    lst = []
    counter = 0
    signs = ["head", "tail"]
    while counter < m:
        toss = choice(signs)
        lst.append(toss)
        if toss == 'tail':
            counter += 1
    return lst

lst = S(10)
print(lst)                # ['head', 'tail', 'head', 'head', 'tail', ...]
print(lst.count('tail'))  # 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want you own code to work, you can just add:

```
counter = 0
```

After the *while* condition.
The mistake in you code is the increment of count. What it does is for one loop, it counts all tails on your list and adds that to counter, then, like a snowball effect, the SAME tails were counted and added AGAIN for every succeeding loops.

This correction is a bit inefficient though as you will always clear the value of count, then count again from the start. If your list reaches large index values, it may slow down your code.

Good luck!